# RabbitMQ: Getting Basic.ConsumeOk reply out of order

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to send a bunch of methods on a single channel to RabbitMQ server in a pipeline and then wait for corresponding synchronous responses. I'm observing a following artifact:

*Client request pipeline:*

`Exchange.Declare` **->** `Queue.Declare` **->** `Queue.Bind` **->** **`Basic.Consume`** **->** **`Basic.Qos`**

*Server response pipeline:*

`Exchange.DeclareOk` **->** `Queue.DeclareOk` **->** `Queue.BindOk` **->** **`Basic.QosOk`** **->** **`Basic.ConsumeOk`**

Notice how the response `Basic.ConsumeOk` is coming after the `Basic.QosOk`, even though the order of requests in pipeline was different. Reading the specs I came to a conclusion that in between a **synchronous request** and a corresponding **response** only an asynchronous methods can be received (`Basic.Deliver`, `Basic.Return`, `Channel.Flow`, `Connection.Close`, `Channel.Close`).

Otherwise, if for example I issue a several `Queue.Declare` requests or even  `Basic.Consume` requests in a row it would be impossible to know which response corresponds to which requests if order is not preserved.

Is this considered normal? Is my understanding is flawed? Or maybe pipelining is not supported by RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a custom library or your own code because pipelining is not supported by RabbitMQ or any of the client libraries that we maintain. It's easy to see when you run some code using an officially supported library.

When I run the sequence of methods you describe using Pika, I see requests and responses sent in the order expected.

I modified `receive.py` in [the code here](https://github.com/lukebakken/rabbitmq-tutorials/tree/55365084/rabbitmq-getting-basic-consumeok-reply-out-of-order/python) as well as included a packet capture from my machine.

I'm using RabbitMQ 3.7.13, Erlang 21.3.2, Python 3.7.2 and Pika 0.13.1.

Comment: Yes, it's my own implementation indeed. If you say that client libraries do not support pipelining, then obviously in Pika you would not observe this effect. Are you the maintainer of RabbitMQ broker? If so, can you please tell me where the docs that describe methods that can be pipelined and those that can not? Obviously the pipelining **must** be supported for `Basic.Publish`.

Comment: I recommend using the RabbitMQ Java Client as the reference implementation for a client library. In the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html) there are methods that return a value, and those that don't. When a value is returned, clients must wait for it to consider that operation complete.

Comment: And when the client waits for an operation to complete, another operation of this kind should not be issued (method should not be sent), is that correct?

Comment: That's correct, I believe. You can send the same method on another channel, of course.